# After finish creating R function; proof the correction by using this function with sample values in vignette. The error said "unused argument (...)"

Tags: r, package, cran

**I am trying to update R package version on CRAN by updating function.** I met a wired situation where, after the function be created.
And the **sample is in the vignette file**

**The sample code I used is**

```
my_function(seasonal.periods = c(7, 365), n = 800, nComp = 2, output_format = "tsibble")
```

The outcome can appears as a lovely tsibble format within R. However, **the vignette document contain this sample cannot be knit out! And the error said**

**unused argument (output_format=tsibble)**
[image]

**But I already defined this parameter within the function. And it can give a result within R (as picture shown below). I wonder if that is because I did not define this parameter properly? Anyone know how to fix that?**

**I wonder is that because vignette cannot be knit out due to new function does not upload to cran? But it should not be?**

[image]

Comment: I tried to run your code. It works fine to me. Try to clean your environment and restart R (Ctrl + Shift + F10). Also add the libraries that you use in your example: `library(gratis);library(tsibble);library(purrr);library(forecast)`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I did restart or clean environment. However,  that sample  in the **R package vignette** file still cannot be knit out.

Comment: have you rebuilt your package correctly before trying to knit your vignette?

Comment: That's sounds like a very good idea to try. How can I rebuild the package? using ```renv::rebuild("package_name", recursive = TRUE)```?

Comment: you can use rstudio's shortcuts: Ctrl+Shift+D [to recreate the documentation] and Ctrl+Shift+B [to rebuild the package]

Comment: Those shortcuts work only if you are in the project of your package, which I assumed you were.

Comment: I tried location on laptop with ```"C:/Users/mreal/Documents/GitHub/package_name/R"``` or only ```"C:/Users/mreal/Documents/GitHub/package_name"```. And then click ```Ctrl+Shift+B``` in RStudio. (Ctrl +Shift+B does not show anything)Then knit **vignette** again. It's not work. Am I did some step wrong?

Comment: try to run these commands: `devtools::document("C:/Users/mreal/Documents/GitHub/package_name"); devtools::install("C:/Users/mreal/Documents/GitHub/package_name")`. `package_name` should be a folder where all the necessary elements are present (`DESCRIPTION` file  and `R` folder)

Comment: You are very genius! Would you mind add your answer to answer part, so that I can accept it. Thank you so much for your helping. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we understood in our dialog between the comments, the problem was related to the fact that you didn't re-build your package before knitting your vignettes. Therefore, the vignettes were still loading the package with the old function that didn't have that extra argument.

Thus, to build (and document) your package from R console run these commands:

```
devtools::document("path/to/your/package/folder/") # to create the documentation
devtools::install("path/to/your/package/folder/")  # to build the package
```

The path has to lead to the folder where the `DESCRIPTION` file and the `R` folder are present. Those are the only absolutely necessary pieces of a minimal package.

Or as RStudio shortcuts (only when you are in the project):

```
Ctrl + Shift + D
Ctrl + Shift + B
```